# Continuous function maps $\mathbb{C}^+\cup \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $G: \mathbb{C}^+\cup \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function where $\mathbb{C}^+=\{x+iy~|~x,y\in\mathbb{R}, y>0\}$.

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, one can define $f_n(x):=G(x+i\frac{1}{n})$ and $f(x):=G(x)$, then by continuity of $G$, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x), \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Is it uniformly convergent?